# Convert Facebook JSON created_time of String format to long format

Tags: android, string, json, facebook, long-integer

I'm working on **android** app and trying to get created_time from **facebook JSON**. I was successful in that and I got it as `2011-07-14T12:28:52+0000` .

Now this should be converted into long format like `220200202932093`

My challenge now is to convert that into long format.

This is because i have planned to get relative time using `getRelativeTimeSpanString` in android.

Please help me to convert String formatted time from JSON object to long format

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
String exampleDateString = "2011-07-14T12:28:52+0000";
try 
{
    long timeMillis = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+SSSS")
        .parse(exampleDateString)
        .getTime();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```